# Lock Python code in Jupyter Notebook and make it executable as command

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the below code running in 4 different cells:

cell1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
reference = pd.read_excel(argument1,sheet_name=argument2,na_values='0',converters={'SID': '{:0>12}'.format}) #reference file path
reference.replace('',np.nan,inplace=True)
reference.dropna(how='all',inplace = True)
reference.drop([0],inplace=True)
```

Cell2:

```
reference=reference[reference['SType']==argument']
```

Cell4:

```
path = argument4
file_list = os.listdir(path)

for i in file_list:
    filename = os.path.join(path, i)
    #ori_df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    cond = pd.Index(df.iloc[0]).intersection(reference.columns)
    df1 = reference[cond].copy()
    #df1.loc[-1] = df1.columns
    d = dict(zip(df.iloc[0], df.columns))
    df1 = df1.sort_index().rename(columns=d)
    x = df1.iloc[:,1:].columns
    df1.dropna(axis=0,how='all',subset=x,inplace=True)
    if len(cond) > 1:
        df1.to_excel(filename,index = False)
    else:
        os.remove(filename)
```

I want to know is there any way that I can save this code as a .py file and make it executable just by passing the arguments like a command line inside jupyter cells. Is it allowed in Jupyter notebook? if yes, Please let me know how.

** Sorry if I am being ignorant here, I tried doing some research on this but couldnot get any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use nbconvert `--to script` option.

```
jupyter-nbconvert --to script path/to/your/notebook.ipynb
```

You will not be able to pass custom argument using command line, that will need some further customization of generated script.

[Relevant documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#executable-script)

> Convert a notebook to an executable script. This is the simplest way
>   to get a Python (or other language, depending on the kernel) script
>   out of a notebook. If there were any magics in an Jupyter notebook,
>   this may only be executable from a Jupyter session.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question not a long time ago ^^

I'm not sure my answer is what you are expecting for, but here is how I did it :

Let's say your files are like this :

```
+
|  my_notebook.ipynb
| + folder1
| | my_script.py
```

And let's say you have a function `run_script()` in the file `my_script.py`

Then you can just do :

```
import folder1.my_script as ms

ms.run_script()
```

---

*In order to be able to call your script as a package/module, you need to create empty `__init__.py` file at the right place. So your tree should be like :*

```
+
|  __init__.py
|  my_notebook.ipynb
| + folder1
| |  __init__.py
| | my_script.py
```