# How to save python script as .py file on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, save, jupyter

I wrote some functions on Jupyter notebook and want to save the script in form of .py, but anaconda jupyter notebook automatically saves the script as .ipynb, How can I change it to .py for this specific script? Is there any command for it? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock Python code in Jupyter Notebook and make it executable as command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831119/lock-python-code-in-jupyter-notebook-and-make-it-executable-as-command)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are [built-in Magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#) in Jupyter:

> IPython has a set of predefined ‘magic functions’ that you can call
>   with a command line style syntax. There are two kinds of magics,
>   line-oriented and cell-oriented. Line magics are prefixed with the %
>   character and work much like OS command-line calls: they get as an
>   argument the rest of the line, where arguments are passed without
>   parentheses or quotes. Lines magics can return results and can be used
>   in the right hand side of an assignment. Cell magics are prefixed with
>   a double %%, and they are functions that get as an argument not only
>   the rest of the line, but also the lines below it in a separate
>   argument.
>
> Magics are useful as convenient functions where Python syntax is not
>   the most natural one, or when one want to embed invalid python syntax
>   in their work flow.

[%%writefile](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-writefile) (Write the contents of the cell to a file)

[%save](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-save) (Save a set of lines or a macro to a given filename)

Comment: usage, please? When I type "%%writefile a.py" in the jupyter, I got this error "UsageError: %%writefile is a cell magic, but the cell body is empty."

Answer (score 36):

You can download a copy of the python as a `.py` script from `FILE` menu in the upper left corner. See this photograph.[image]

That should do it!

Comment: The answer isn't functioning properly. The menu only offers the option to download, with no other choices available. Upon clicking "download," it only downloads a file named "*.ipynb", that's not *.py file.

Comment: So you do not see those other options, when you click the arrow to the right of Download As? Because the answer is correct, unless you have something going on sideways with your instance. I just checked and it is not at the top, but it is still there on my version (and it is a different laptop and version of everything than I used to answer this question)

Comment: I checked again and compare with the online version provided by Jupyter, they are different. From the online jupyter, I can see the download and sub-manual with options, such as save to ipynb or py, but when install and run locally, there is only download, but no sub-options.

Comment: You should be able to download a .py file from the downloads. Technically that is what it is called even when you run Jupyter notebook locally because you are running a server in a container that provides the ipython capabilities. When you download you can save the .py anywhere you want, and open it with any python IDE's The markdown cells are converted to comments

Answer (score 16):

you can try this in command line

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python mnist.py.ipynb.
```

to convert all

```
 jupyter nbconvert --to python *.ipynb
```

For past versions:

you can try this in command line

```
ipython nbconvert --to python mnist.py.ipynb.
```

to convert all

```
 ipython nbconvert --to python *.ipynb
```

Comment: Thank you,
ipython nbconvert --to python *.ipynb
Helped me

Comment: Nowadays gives: [TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython nbconvert` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. You likely want to use `jupyter nbconvert` in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using jupytext.
Install jupytext

`pip install jupytext`

Edit the file below

`.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py`

Add this code snippet to the bottom of your script. This will save to both a `py` file and a `ipynb` file when the notebook is saved.

```
c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class="jupytext.TextFileContentsManager"
c.ContentsManager.formats = "ipynb,py"
```