# Unable to covert a Jupyter notebook script to .py

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, task, scheduler

I am new to programming. I wrote a script that runs well on Jupyter. But when I am trying to convert it in .py the program doesn't run. Need guidance on the same.

**Purpose of converting notebook to .py**
I am trying to convert the notebook script to .py so that I can schedule this on task scheduler. In case there is a way in which I can directly run the notebook on task scheduler, I may not need the conversion.

Else need guidance on how to convert from notebook to .py properly. Code and error is shown below -

```py
port = 587  # For starttls
SMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com"

import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

file_path = r'C:\Users\sarashiv\Documents\Python\Contract tracker\Tracker.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'Data')

print(type(df['Days left']))

df1 = df[df['Days left']<30]

list1 = df1['Vendor Name']

list_carriers = list(list1)

for i in list_carriers:
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    df_temp = df1[df1['Vendor Name']==i]

    mail.To = 'shiva.saran82@gmail.com'
    mail.Subject = f" {i} - Contract expiry notification - (Test mail please ignore)"
    mail.HTMLBody = '''<h3>The below contracts are expiring.</h3>
                   {}'''.format(df_temp.to_html())
    mail.Send()
```

Error when I am trying to run this file in .py is as below. I am running this on visual studio

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\sarashiv\Documents\Python\Contract tracker\Tracker.xlsx'

This file exists at this location because this path is working well with notebook. So please help!!

Comment: Perhaps try the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676850/python-script-cant-find-file-when-opening-with-vs-code-but-works-ok-with-termi?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save python script as .py file on jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885901/how-to-save-python-script-as-py-file-on-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Hi mightyandweakcoder, Thanks for sharing this. I learnt a new way to convert notebook to .py. But I keep running into the same problem. File not found error

Comment: Tried the cwd method but the seems there was some other issue. I copy pasted the same code on a new .py file and this worked. Thanks guys for the response. Really appreciate this!