# jupyter notebook: NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Every time that i try to launch my notebook im getting the error below .
let's specify that im new worker on the project and the file config.py was created before that i joined the team.

Does anyone knows how to resolve it please?

**The code actually done is**

Requirements.txt

```
psycopg2==2.7.3.2.  
SQLAlchemy==1.2.2
pandas==0.21.0
docker==3.3.0
python-json-logger
sshtunnel==0.1.4
jupyter
jupytext==1.2
geopy==2.2.0
```

errror detail

```
~/SG/notebooks/config.py in <module>
1 # Using jupytext
----> 2 c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class = "jupytext.TextFileContentsManager"
3 c.ContentsManager.default_jupytext_formats = "ipynb,py"

NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

code

the row causing the error in the notebook is

```
  from src.util.connect_postgres import postgres_connexion
```

the content of the file connect_postgres

```
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 from config.util.database import TARGET_TEST_HOST, TARGET_PROD_HOST, \
 TARGET_TEST_DB, TARGET_PROD_DB, TARGET_TEST_USER, TARGET_PROD_USER, SG_PROD_USER, SG_PROD_HOST
 from config.secrets.passwords import TARGET_PROD_PWD, TARGET_TEST_PWD, SG_PROD_PWD
 from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
 import psycopg2

 def _create_engine_psg(user, db, host, port, pwd):
 """ Returns a connection object to PostgreSQL """
 url = build_postgres_url(db, host, port, pwd, user)
 return create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
 def build_postgres_url(db, host, port, pwd, user):
 url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(user, pwd, host, port, db)
 return url
 def postgres_connexion(env):
  if env == 'prod':
  return create_engine_psg_with_tunnel_ssh(TARGET_PROD_DB, 
  TARGET_PROD_USER, TARGET_PROD_PWD, SG_PROD_PWD,
                                         SG_PROD_USER, 
   SG_PROD_HOST, TARGET_PROD_HOST)
  else:
    raise ValueError("'env' parameter must be 'prod'.")
```

config.py

```
  c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class = "jupytext.TextFileContentsManager"
  c.ContentsManager.default_jupytext_formats = "ipynb,py"
```

I red that i can generate the file and then edit it.

when i tried to create the jupyter_notebook_config it is always in my personal directory of marczhr

```
  /Users/marczhr/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

but i want to be done in my something that i can push on git.

Hope that im clear ^^

Thank you,

Comment: A lot of the code snippets in your post doesn't really help in answering the question. The only thing here that matter is `config.py`, where `c` is defined / instantiated. If you can post your `config.py` that would be much easier for us to work with.

Comment: config.py exist already in my orignal post . Than you ^^ @onlyphantom

Comment: How are you starting the notebook?

Comment: "but i want to be done in my something that i can push on git.": I'd advise against that: configuration files are system or user specific in this case, not project specific. If there is some configuration that should apply to the project, you should find another type of configuration file, or perhaps better, programmatically add it to the relevant code.

Comment: @9769953 to start the notebook i did  jupyter notebook --config="config.py"

Comment: And that's not causing any error?

Comment: no there is no error .

Comment: What do you think the `c.` in your config file refers to? The problem is clearly that it's apparently meaningless and undefined.

Comment: i don't know so much but the two rows aims to create .py when we wnat to create .ipynb file . @deceze

Comment: I get an error when starting a notebook with (just) these two lines in the config file.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure what you mean, since the `c` is defined by Jupyter's configuration file reader. It's part of the standard Jupyter configuration file. The fact that it's not recognised here, means Jupyter is messed up, or Jupyter isn't actually Jupyter, or something along those files.

Comment: I think you're better off asking your team. It looks like there are some very specific project alterations here that are hard to debug over the internet.

Comment: no one knows and the person who did the job left the company! i thin he was following this link , please have a look                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885901/how-to-save-python-script-as-py-file-on-jupyter-notebook/69347058#69347058

Comment: @9769953 do you see how to do please?

Comment: If no one knows, and the responsible person is gone, try without that configuration file, and see how far you get. I see no dependencies on the Jupyter configuration in the code you've shown (which would have been an odd thing anyway, in my opinion), so perhaps you don't need it.

Comment: Another thing of note: the requirements.txt file has several old, and probably outdated, version numbers. Since, however, some requirements do not have a version specification, you may end up with conflicts. For example, Jupyter will be installed as the latest version, but the Jupytext version is some two years old. These two may by conflict with each other. Pandas 0.21 is from 2017, psycopg2 has gotten quite a revamp and is now somewhat split into two packages (and psycopg2-binary is likely what you want) etc etc.

Comment: From all the above, it seems the project/team really need to get someone onboard that knows their Python shit and gets the project back up to date. That will be a lot better than trying and asking on the internet, where people only have limited insight in the project.

Comment: I've just spotted the actual error while I was going through your question again. My above comments still stand, but see my answer as to the actual solution to your problem. It's a simple nameclash, quite common for beginners, and easy to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the notebook from the directory with the configuration file.

The reason is that there is an import with a config module or package in the code listed. By launching the notebook from the directory with the configuration file, it will import that Jupyter configuration file, instead of the correct package or module, with the resulting error.

Instead, run it from somewhere else, or put the configuration file elsewhere.

Or perhaps best, take the two configuration lines and add them to the end of your `/Users/marczhr/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file, then remove the 2-3 line `config.py` file.

In the latter case, you can now launch the notebook server from anywhere, and you don't need to specify any configuration file, since Jupyter will automatically use the generated (with added lines) one.

If you want to keep the `config.py` file, then launch the Jupyter notebook server from another directory, and simply specify the full path, like

```
jupyter --config=$HOME/SG/notebooks/config.py
```

All in all, this is a classic nameclash upon import, because of identically named files/directories. Always be wary of that.

(I've commented on some other potential problems in the comments: that still stands, but is irrelevant to the current problem here.)

Comment: thank you for you help @9769953 Sorry i was offline! it is really useful . Last question please: if i decieded to keep the file config.py as it is actually i did the command jupyter notebook --config=`"Users/marczhr/SG/notebooks/config.py"`
from my SG directry i got the same error either. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm. So, `cd ~/SG ; jupyter notebook --config="Users/marczhr/SG/notebooks/config.py"` give the same error? What's your PYTHONPATH? E.g., `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: it gives nothing

Comment: i think there is no $PYTHONPATH here

Comment: What gives nothing? The `jupyter` command, or the `echo` command?

Comment: Ok sorry it's my fault i mean when i tried echo $PYTHONPATH  i had nothing as result.

Comment: And thus the exact same error when starting `jupyter` as above? Have you checked that there is no `config.py` file lying around in the `~/SG` directory?

Comment: in your second proposition you said **if you want to keep the config.py** so i keep it

Comment: That's not my question. Is there a config.py file in the `~/SG` directory?

Comment: yes there one config.py.

Comment: So there is a config.py in the ~/SG directory, *and* there is a config.py file in the ~/SG/notebooks/ directory? Are they the same?

Comment: As per the first sentence in this answer: "Don't run the notebook from the directory with the configuration file.". I also show how to use the current config.py file when running from another directory.